# Capybara does not wait for icons to load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, integration-testing

I am running a Ruby on Rails integration test in Capybara. It is currently failing because a panel is overlapping a button that I need to click on. So, I am  trying to click on an icon with id #click-to-close which will close the panel, and then click on the button under it. However, the close icon is not appearing when I run the Capybara test.

Here is the button in question - it uses the font awesome double-angle (>>) icon.

```
<div class="fa fa-angle-double-right fa-lg right-sidebar-show close-button" id="click-to-close"></div>
```

Here is the part of the Capybara test I am working with:

```
page.accept_confirm do
  sleep 5.seconds #wait for help dash to appear
  page.save_screenshot "XPath.png"
  page.find("#click-to-close").click
  sleep 5.seconds #wait for help dash to disappear
  click_on "Remove", wait: 25, match: :first
end
```

Here is a screenshot of the panel at the time the test is being executed.
[image]

Here is a screenshot of how the panel should look with the close icon.
[image]

Comment: Which driver are you using?

Comment: I'm unsure what a driver is :D

Comment: https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#drivers  - You would most likely be using selenium (default for JS tests), poltergeist, or capybara-webkit. Selenium would open an actual browser on your desktop the other two are headless

Comment: We are using webkit

Comment: What version of Qt did you build it with?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116587/discussion-between-keyan-r-and-tom-walpole).

Comment: From chat - you are running capybara-webkit with Qt 5.5.1 -- you may be running into one of these two issues - https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/808  - https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/728 - where all web fonts are replaced with Arial -- If Arial doesn't have a character at the codepoint you're code is using then nothing will display.

Comment: One solution would probably be for your team to fork the capybara-webkit gem, remove the function that overrides webfonts - https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/blob/master/src/WebPage.cpp#L115 - and then use that.  The method is only there to maintain compatibility with Qt 4.8 which has so many other issues as to be mostly unusable with a modern app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running into this issue: 
https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/808 
https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/728

The optimal solution is to make the entire top bar of the dash clickable, and have the Capybara automated test search for the ID of the top bar and click it. Not enough information was given in the question, but let's say the ID was #top-bar. You would do:

```
page.accept_confirm do
  sleep 5.seconds #wait for help dash to appear
  page.find("#top-bar").click
  click_on "Remove", wait: 25, match: :first
end
```